# Count code lines by extension and path pattern

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I have a bash query that helps me with code lines counting:

```sh
find . "(" -name "*.ext" ")" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

I'd like also to count code lines in specific directories with some pattern (e.g, all th directories starting with "@" symbol). However, it seems that `-name` argument checks only filename, not full name or path.

So, I thought I can use `grep` to filter output, which contains full paths:

```sh
find . "(" -name "*.ext" ")" -print0 | grep "/@" | xargs -0 wc -l
```

But grep doesn't handle it:

> Binary file (standard input) matches

I also tried to removing `-print0` from `find` and adding `-a` to `grep`:

```sh
find . "(" -name "*.ext" ")" | grep -a "/@" | xargs -0 wc -l
```

This way I get file list filtered by path, but it also leads to problem with `xargs`:

> open: File name too long

How can I accomplish the desired result? Also, an explanation how it works and why my last query fails would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems to be right, but the commands usage is not quite right. When you did `find . "(" -name "*.ext" ")" -print0 | grep "/@"` you are passing the whole search results from the `find` command which are NULL delimited as the content to be searched on for `grep`, but it doesn't like the type of data it is seeing.

Usually `grep` identifies if a file is binary or not by seeing first few bytes of its input stream (from file or through stdin). Since you are passing the results from `find` with a NULL delimiter, it was not able to identify it as a text input and considered it binary data and threw error on the same.

Later you bypassed it with the `-a` flag to consider the given binary data as text data, you are now searching on the entire null delimited result for `/@`, but the search results displayed are *not* unique results that match your pattern, but still the whole original result from the `find` command. The workaround you can do, it to let know `grep` to put results with a NULL termination by adding a `-z` flag as

```
find . -name "*.ext" -print0 | grep -az "/@" | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Alternatively, you can use the regex options supported in `find` itself. Assuming you want to search for files with `.ext` on directories starting with `@`, you could do

```
find . -type f -regex ".*[@].*/.*ext" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The `-print0` option from man page:

> -print0
>             True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline character  that 
>   -print  uses).

You used `grep` on a one line output.
Also, this option doesn't print the full path if you run with path `.`.

So, i would suggest:

`find . "(" -name "*.ext" ")" -exec readlink -f {} \;|grep "/@"|xargs wc -l`

Comment: Thanks! Your approach works correctly, but [Inian's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57988004/5308802) seems to be faster.